# How does Instagram lock down their photo upload private API endpoint?

Tags: security, rest, instagram

I'm in the process of building a REST API for a mobile application I'm working on. Like Instagram, I'm considering locking down some of the endpoints such that they would only be accessible from my mobile app (like their photo upload endpoints).

Has anyone have any insight as to how they locked down certain endpoints to only their app? I imagine a possible solution was the use of a shared secret to sign these specific requests and have it verified server-side before processing the upload.

Comment: Why not sniff the network traffic with Wireshark?

Comment: and also dumping the classes and inspecting the executable running with cycript on a jailbroken app over ssh is a good idea for getting the hash generation algorithms (been there, done that, but not for instagram unfortunatelly)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they

1. Check the request header for User-Agent == "Instagram"
2. Check that there is a valid authentication cookie set
3. Sign the body of their requests with some sort of hash.

I'm not sure how the hash is created.

Check this out for some of the documentation, but it looks like the authentication section has been blanked out.

https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki